# Using Spectrum's openWithLink

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the Spectrum color picker to work as it is in their documentation; I'd like to use a button to toggle the color picker to keep the interface tidy. For whatever reason, it's not working.

```js
$("#btn-toggle").click(function() {
  $("#toggle").spectrum("toggle");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
<link href="http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/spectrum.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sp-replacer sp-light">
  <div class="sp-preview">
    <div class="sp-preview-inner" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 205);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn-toggle">Toggle</button>
```

https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#skinning-nonInput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a key part of your HTML & JS - you haven't actually created an input for the Spectrum color picker, nor initialized it.

The JS snippet you've copied is just an example of how to trigger the `toggle` method of an **existing** Spectrum color picker; but you still have to setup the color picket itself.

Add this to your HTML:

```
<input type='text' id="toggle" />
```

You should then remove the `<div class="sp-replacer sp-light">` element as that will be automatically & dynamically-generated by the plug-in when initialized.

Then add this to your JS:

```
$("#toggle").spectrum({
    color: "rgb(255, 235, 205)"
});
// or even just $("#toggle").spectrum(); to initialize it with the default color
```

Full working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/gkz8ukhb/

Also, in your sample HTML, you have jQuery being loaded *after* Spectrum but since the Spectrum plug-in requires jQ, you need to load it first or you'd get a `jQuery is not defined` error.

Comment: Beautiful, cheers! I was pulling my hair out not understanding it. Is the toggle method how they display the open with link approach in the documentation? How would I go about hiding the box and only displaying the picker/chooser when I click a button? I can open a new question if you like. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, you could apply CSS to hide the `.sp-replacer` element that the widget creates when initialized; then your button would be the only way to toggle the color picker, which it sounds like is what you want. The rule would simply be `.sp-replacer {display:none}` - I've forked the JSFiddle to include that & some other touches (like accessing the selected value for the color picker when hidden) here: https://jsfiddle.net/sen9ut8s/

Comment: Bless you, sir!